# Are there "distracted flying" laws for GA other than laws against reckless flying?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, general-aviation

I am aware of the sterile cockpit rule for airliners, but are there any laws against "distracted flying" (analogous to distracted driving laws, or the sterile cockpit rule for airliners) for general aviation pilots, aside from the general prohibition on reckless or careless flying?

Comment: What is according to you the difference between distracted flying and careless operation of the aircraft?

Comment: @Sanchises there might be cases where using an electronic device or doing something else potentially distracting isn't considered careless or reckless, but the FAA still wants to prohibit it. IIUC that's why the sterile cockpit rule exists for airliners; it wouldn't exist if any violations of it were already covered by the rule against careless or reckless flying. Also, if operating a vehicle while using a mobile device or other potential distraction was always reckless, there would be no distracted driving laws as they would be covered by reckless driving laws.

Comment: There is no sterile cockpit rule in the FARs, although most airlines have a policy.  However, sterile cockpit simply means no idle conservations unrelated to the task on hand below a certain altitude.  Nothing to do with handheld devices.

Comment: @MichaelHall the sterile cockpit rule is in the FARs in Parts 121 and 135, but not Part 91. It's in 14 CFR 121.542 and 14 CFR 135.100. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_flight_deck_rule

Comment: Mobile device use is explicitly prohibited by 14 CFR 121.542(d): "During all flight time as defined in 14 CFR 1.1, no flight crewmember may use, nor may any pilot in command permit the use of, a personal wireless communications device (as defined in 49 U.S.C. 44732(d)) or laptop computer while at a flight crewmember duty station unless the purpose is directly related to operation of the aircraft, or for emergency, safety-related, or employment-related communications, in accordance with air carrier procedures approved by the Administrator."

Comment: I stand corrected on devices, but the conversationally sterile cockpit concept during critical phases of flight has been around long before cell phones.

Comment: What does & doesn't qualify as "distracted" in cars & what's unacceptable in aircraft can be pretty different. A long-running conversation in the car might not be distracting at all, but would violate sterile cockpit rules below 10,000'. OTOH, reading an approach plate (on paper or an EFB) is entirely allowed - and required - in the cockpit, but would be intensely distracting in a car. The differences in the environments (close proximity of other cars, capability of autopilots vs cruise control, cognitive task loading, etc) drive some pretty different expectations in the 1 case vs the other.

Comment: @RalphJ, that's a better answer than mine...  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Because how would observation of the infraction and enforcement work?

Comment: The same way it often happens with "distracted driving" - as part of accident reconstruction, a driver (or pilot) admits to doing things they should not have been doing.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that’s far different than a cop pulling someone over after seeing them texting while driving.  Distracted driving laws are intended to prevent accidents.  Once an accident happens it’s too late to do any good.

Comment: That is true. But I think (could be wrong) that in the case of a car accident, they can charge a driver with "distracted driving" or similar, if they believe that is part of the cause of the accident, much as DUI can be charged both at a routine traffic stop and after an accident. Whether similar rules apply for flying, I don't know.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, True, but given that aviation accidents generally have far more dire outcomes, such a charge after the fact would just be piling on.  Again, these sort of laws are intended to be preventative by discouraging behaviors that might lead to an accident.